# changing CNAME record, will it affect existing email addresses

Tags: email, dns, redirects

I need to forward a domainA to redirect to domainB. I've been doing this via CNAME records but for this situation I need to leave email addresses for domainA intact and unaffected while redirecting web traffic. Would this be safe if using a CNAME change?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is the MX record that is used for the email server.