# Change host / keep emails

Tags: web-hosting, email

I haven't done this before so I gotta ask.
I'm doing a site for a client. The current site is done in PHP, and I'll do it in ASP.NET.
Now, the current hosting service does not support ASP.NET code, so I'll have to change the hosting provider, and that's fine, BUT, the client SPECIFICALLY asked that the email adresses stay the same.
Is this doable and if yes, how?
So only the hosting provider changes, the domain name stays the same.

Tnx for your time!
Andrej

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) Create the email accounts on the new server

2) Have the customer download any emails they wish to keep off of the old server (if they haven't done so already)

3) After business hours change the DNS records to reflect the new host's nameservers (and by extensions MX records)

4) If the mail settings have changed, have the customer update their email client to connect to the new mail server.

5) Some emails may still get routed to the old server. Have the customer check this by either using webmail (if available) or using their old IP address for the mail server.

Comment: Good call about the misrouted emails during the DNS transition. I've never really stopped to think about that one.

Comment: Nobody does until their customer freaks out about a missing email. Then you never forget to check again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can check [changing CNAME record, will it affect existing email addresses](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/changing-cname-record-will-it-affect-existing-email-addresses/5921#5921) almost the same case. Also have in mind that you can change the email vendor and still keep the email address.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in having mail hosted at one place and web at another. If the current hosting service has a package for mail only I'd suggest you switch to that one when the site is moved.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt anwser! Yes, but that would requiire I ask the client to pay for the hosting at two places (one for mail, one for website), and I think they would not agree to that! :)